# Orchard and news / announcements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Is there something build in Orchard or modules available for news and announcements management?
Seems to be a very common thing but have been unable to find anything about it.

I would like to place this on my start page to give a head ups of the latest news (the items itself would be stored on sql server compact). This would be in a table like structure.

*Logged in users should be able to post news as well.*

Any recommendations on a approach or what documents i should read up for this  would be greatly appreciated, so i do not waste time using a wrong approach or not taking advantage of what Orchard has to offer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a module for that.
I would create a new contenttype called "news" with title and bodypart attached to it. Then you can add widget as its stereotype and then it will become available in the list of widgets. Then you can create a new widget of this type. Then you can place this widget into the "homepage" layerrule.

Comment: feel free to ask more